# How to display two different types of components based on a boolean variable in jsf?

Tags: jsf

I have thought about this for a while - not getting a good idea.

This is the problem. I will have to display a text either in a text box or as an output text. How do I do this using a boolean variable in JSF?

I do not want to make an h:inputText and disable/make read only, it based on the boolean , I want to display a clean label or an output text.

suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of the `rendered` attribute. It takes a boolean expression.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" rendered="#{bean.editmode}" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.input}" rendered="#{!bean.editmode}" />
```

If the expression evaluates `true`, the component will be rendered in the component tree and be visible in the generated HTML output. If it evaluates `false`, it will not be rendered and thus not be emitted to the HTML output.

Here are several other examples how you could express a boolean expression.

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.intValue > 10}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.objectValue == null}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.stringValue != 'someValue'}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!empty bean.collectionValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!bean.booleanValue && bean.intValue != 0}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.stringValue == 'oneValue' || bean.stringValue == 'anotherValue'}" />
```