# Conditionally displaying JSF components in an if-else

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 1.2 and I have the following output format:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{txt.text_a}">
    <f:param value="#{bean.get_a}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

And I have also the following output text:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.get_b}" />
```

I would like to display them conditionally in an if-else case. In the backing bean, I have a boolean property `visible` for that. How can I implement it in an if-else case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display two different types of components based on a boolean variable in jsf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134515/how-to-display-two-different-types-of-components-based-on-a-boolean-variable-in)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using two different blocks with the opposite `rendered` condition, as follows:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{txt.text_a}" rendered="#{visible}">
  <f:param value="#{bean.get_a}" />
</h:outputFormat>  
<h:outputText value="#{bean.get_b}" rendered="#{not visible}" />
```

Where `visible` represents the condition for the `text_a` to be displayed.